# How can do this CustomTableView – Complex for me

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need make [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFXuB.png) CustomView or CustomTableView, I'm parsing a XML to provide the data, show all cells normal is easy but need that the first cell must be like at the sample image, the other cells are normal, i don't have idea how do it.

Please help me, other thing how can leave the padding or margin same the image??

Comment: You just need to create 2 different custom cells in the storyboard (or in xibs) with different reuse identifiers -- if the indexPath.row == 0, dequeue one type, and if it's anything else, dequeue the other.

Comment: I need try this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple to such a thing. Look into header views for `UITableView` to get the big main header. and then use the other cells as you normally would, through `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Your're ***other*** option is to make a custom `UIView` with an `UIView` seperate from `UITableView` for the header and a regular tableView for the rest.

Comment: It is a good solution, I will try this.

Comment: If this is a good solution, please accept my answer and if really helped you upvote it :)